# Format two kinds of factor dates in R

Tags: r

I have two sets of date looking strings; either `31.3.14` or `31/3/14`

I would like to format them to `31-3-2014`

Now I know how to format each of them to desired format, but I don't know how to distinguish them and apply the approach bellow.

For this format `31.3.14` :

```
  format(as.Date(as.character("31.3.14"), "%d.%m.%y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

For this format `31/3/14` :

```
  format(as.Date(as.character("31/3/14"), "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

I have this sorts of dates in a dataframe column randomly so I would need to apply given method for the right set of format.

EDIT: sorry I have also different kinds of dates, also: `"2013-04-01"` here the solution provided with `dmy` function fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could also do it with base R by removing punctuations first

```
Dates <- c("31.3.14", "31/3/14")
format(as.Date(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "-", Dates), format = "%d-%m-%y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
## [1] "31-03-2014" "31-03-2014"
```

Answer (score 3):

Hadley Wickham's Lubridate package makes this easy.

```
> require(lubridate)
> test <- data.frame(raw = c("31.3.14", "31/3/14"))
> test$formatted <- dmy(test$raw)
> test
      raw  formatted
1 31.3.14 2014-03-31
2 31/3/14 2014-03-31
```

EDIT: 
Based on the edit to the question, one can use `ifelse()` within a function to detect a four-digit sequence at the start of the date string.

```
require(stringr)
myDateFun <- function(x){
  z <- ifelse(str_detect(x, "^\\d{4}") == TRUE,
              ymd(x), dmy(x) )
  z <- as.POSIXlt(z, origin = "1970-01-01")
  z <- format(z, "%Y-%m-%d")
  return(z)
}
test <- data.frame(raw = c("31.3.14", "31/3/14", "2014-3-31"))


test$formatted.2 <- myDateFun(test$raw)
test
        raw  formatted formatted.2
1   31.3.14 2014-03-31  2014-03-31
2   31/3/14 2014-03-31  2014-03-31
3 2014-3-31       <NA>  2014-03-31
```

Comment: (+1) thank you, but I have started with ifelse, but that's bit clumsy solution.